# Which mechanism do ethers follow when cleaved by hydrogen halides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, ethers

Ethers can be cleaved under acidic conditions by treatment with hydrogen halides (HX, where X = Cl/Br/I). Some of these reactions proceed by S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanisms and some by S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanisms. How can I tell which mechanism is being followed?

Answer (score 7):

The first step of this reaction is always a proton transfer:

[image: Protonation of ether by HX]

Then, the substitution follows either the S<sub>N</sub>2 or S<sub>N</sub>1 pathway depending on whether R is methyl, primary, secondary, or tertiary.

**Methyl and primary ethers** undergo acidic cleavage by the S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism:

[image: SN2 process for methyl or primary ethers]

**Tertiary ethers** undergo cleavage by the S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism:

[image: SN1 process for tertiary ethers]

**Secondary ethers** probably undergo cleavage by both mechanisms competing with each other.

Note that unless R' is an aryl group, the alcohol R'OH that forms will also be converted into a halide by a similar mechanism.

Read more at [any of the sites in this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ether+nucleophilic+substitution).

Comment: I suppose you were to say: If R is primary... or secondary... or tertiary... . I don't think you can extend this notation from alcohols to ethers, it is ambiguous which carbon you are referring to.

Comment: Hey, my teacher told that no matter what ether is it, it will always go through SN2 if the HX used is **anhydrous**. Is it true? Does **anhydrous** HX guarantee SN2? Thanks

Comment: @An_Elephant Did you get an answer somewhere?

Comment: @Silica19 Yes, the SN2 will be major.

Comment: @An_Elephant Will it be SN2 even for a tertiary alkyl group? If yes, can you please share a source? Thanks.

Comment: @Silica19 According to my teacher the major will be SN2. Unfortunately, I do not know any online source. Sorry :(